# Tagging friends in status updates?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I tried the @[userid:name] method but it always comes up a blank tag. For example if "I say Hello @[123456:John Smith] how are you?" It comes up "Hello How are you?" and the tag is completely blank.

Each time I do it, I always make sure the userID matches up with the name, and is one of my friends. Please tell me what is going wrong. Has tagging friends in feed messages been deprecated, or has another way about doing it been implemented?

Another user who had the same issue was this poster here:
[Tagging friends in status updates from Facebook API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4327353/tagging-friends-in-status-updates-from-facebook-api)
I believe it is unresolved stil.

Answer (score 1):

This is still not available via the graph API. They closed the loophole you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Developers Blog: **Bringing Mention Tagging to Open Graph**
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/